# Lineshift when using pagecommand in pdfpages

Tags: paragraphs, pdfpages

I'm using pdfpages to import pdf as attachment in a report where I use pagecommand to write the title for each attachment.

Is there a way to get a lineshift/new paragraph between "Attachment 1" and "Pre-project report" in the code snippet below?

```
\includepdf[pages=1, scale=0.9, pagecommand=\Huge{\textbf{Attachment 1 - Pre-project report}}, offset=0 -1cm]{thesis/Attachments/Attachment1.pdf}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand*\mytitle{{\Huge\bfseries Attachment 1 \par Pre-project report\par}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1, scale=0.9, pagecommand={\mytitle}, offset=0 -1cm]{notes.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @EivindFugledal If it works, please accept the answer, otherwise it will dwell forever on the list of questions without an accepted answer.